# Async/Promise issues when adding a Gatsby node field

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, gatsby

I'm having some issues adding some fields on to a Gatsby node. The real issue comes down to the fact that I just can't seem to wrap my head around the asynchronous situation, since I'm creating these fields from API call results. I'm still trying to learn about promises/async/etc.

I make one API call to an API to get location information and add it as a field (locationRequest, which is working just fine), and then run another call to get the orthodontists that work at that location.

When getOrthos runs, and it gets up to the console.log that should be spitting out an array of orthodontist entities, I'm getting this instead:

`Created Ortho Node... [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]`

What am I doing wrong? I've tried to go through some Promise tutorials, but I can't figure out the best way to do this where it returns the actual data rather than the promise.

Thank you for any guidance you can provide, and please excuse my ignorance.

```
    const yextOrthos = node.acf.location_orthodontists;

    const locationRequest = async () => {
        const data = await fetch("https://FAKEURL.COM")
        .then(response => response.json());

        if( data && data.response && data.response.count === 1 ){
            createNodeField({
                node,
                name: `yextLocation`,
                value: data.response.entities[0]
            });
        } else {
            console.log("NO LOCATIONS FOUND");
        }
    };

    const getOrthos = async () => {
        let orthodontists = await yextOrthos.map( async (ortho, i) => {
            let orthoID = ortho.acf.yext_entity_ortho_id;
            return await orthoRequest(orthoID);
        });

        if( orthodontists.length ){
            createNodeField({
                node,
                name: `yextOrthos`,
                value: orthodontists
            });
            console.log("Created Ortho Node...", orthodontists);
        } else {
            console.log("NO DOCTORS FOUND");
        }
    };

    const orthoRequest = async (orthoID) => {
        const dataPros = await fetch("https://FAKEURL.COM").then(response => response.json());

        if( dataPros && dataPros.response && dataPros.response.count === 1 ){
            return dataPros.response.entities[0];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    locationRequest();
    getOrthos();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Promise.all() for arrays, on this line:

```
let orthodontists = await Promise.all(yextOrthos.map( async (ortho, i) => {...});
```

I hope it helps!

Edit:

> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async
>   function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within
>   the async function.
>
> If you wish to fully perform two or more jobs in parallel, you must
>   use await Promise.all([job1(), job2()]) as shown in the parallel
>   example.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick, and I was able to clean up the code quite a bit once I knew that was the culprit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

What you need to remember is that await should only stand before promise or something that returns promise. `Array.prototype.map()` returns `array` so you can't use await with it directly. `Promise.all()` on the other hand accepts an array and returns a promise. The example Jose Vasquez gave seems sufficient.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Much appreciated.